# Como puedo insertar una fecha a la base de datos sin que me salga 0000-00-00?

Tags: php

Esta es la pagina principal, donde he creado un calendario interactivo

```
    <form id="frm" method="get" action="data.php">

    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Registrar informacion">

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth:true,
                changeYear:true,    
                firstDay: 1,
                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febreo', 'Marzo',
                'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
                'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
                'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab']
            });
        });

    </script>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Les dejo la otra parte donde quiero insertar la fecha, si lo registra pero como 0000-00-00 y me arroga el error

> Undefined index: fecha_recibido in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEDEMA\data.php on line 6.

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");


$fecha_recibido = $_POST["fecha_recibido"];

$query  = "INSERT INTO oficios_recibidos (fecha_recibido) VALUES ('$fecha_recibido')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te dice el error:

```
Undefined index: fecha_recibido in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEDEMA\data.php on line 6
```

el índice fecha_recibido no lo encuentra.

Estas enviando el formulario por get y recibiéndolo por post, cambia el method del formulario a post y añade un name="fecha_recibido" a tu input del datepicker.

te dejo el ejemplo:

```
  <form id="frm" method="post" action="data.php">

<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="fecha_recibido">
<input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Registrar informacion">

<script>
    $(function () {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true,    
            firstDay: 1,
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febreo', 'Marzo',
            'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
            'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
            'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab']
        });
    });

</script>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: @HectorAntonioCiriacoChavez si no te funcionara, prueba a hacer un var_dump($_POST); antes de declarar $fecha_recibido para comprobar que recibes en con el post y tener algo más de información